# finding which tier 1 or isp to connect to to reduce latency

Tags: ip, latency, colocation

I am looking to connect to 4 location p,q,r,s. I a ntrying to find the set of locations where I should connect to (isp or pop) to minimize latency . Is it lower latency to connect to a tier 1 network which would connect to 4 ip p,p,r,s ? Is there a lower latency path to connect p,q,r,s through a tier 2 network ? how do I find this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get a sample of your target end-user IPs you can typically get the provider to let you trace route to those destinations and look at which provider has best network proximity. Many providers have a looking-glass type server that will permit you to test this yourself. Others you may have to get someone technical on the sales side of the house to assist.

Tier-1 colocation may require you to purchase cross-connects to multiple providers. Mileage may vary ...
Try looking for providers that peer with multiple tier-1 networks at regional NAP facilities.
Tier-1 colocation can be sticky in some circumstances. Tier-2 and even some of the smaller hosting outfits have great colocation deals that you can leverage. Very cost competitive and fantastic support folks. Look at all your options, read customer reviews on the Internet, talk to the sales people and ask them the hard questions.